# How to disable block directory?

Tags: block-editor

I cant find a way to disable listing new blocks from the block directory in the editor. In the editor, if you search for something, third party blocks show up and ask you if you want to install them.

[image]

Is it possible to disable the block directory? I dont want other users to install blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Excerpt from [Editor Hooks → Block Directory](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/editor-filters/#block-directory) in the block editor handbook:

> The Block Directory enables installing new block plugins from
> [WordPress.org](https://wordpress.org/plugins/browse/block/). It can
> be disabled by removing the actions that enqueue it. In WordPress
> core, the function is `wp_enqueue_editor_block_directory_assets`. To
> remove the feature, use
> [`remove_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_action/),
> like this:
>
> ```
> <?php
> // my-plugin.php
>
> remove_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'wp_enqueue_editor_block_directory_assets' );
> ```

So just use the above code to globally disable the block directory.

- You can also do something like so, which disables the block directory based on the current user's *role*:

  ```php
  add_action( 'init', 'my_disable_block_directory_plugin' );
  function my_disable_block_directory_plugin() {
      // Define a list of allowed user roles.
      $allowed_roles = array( 'administrator' );

      // Check whether the current user has any of the above allowed user roles.
      $roles_filtered = array_intersect(
          $allowed_roles,
          (array) wp_get_current_user()->roles
      );

      // If the user does not have any of that roles, disable the Block Directory.
      if ( empty( $roles_filtered ) ) {
          remove_action(
              'enqueue_block_editor_assets',
              'wp_enqueue_editor_block_directory_assets'
          );
      }
  }
  ```

And just so that you know, it can also be disabled via JavaScript:

```js
// This way, you can register it back later, if necessary.
wp.plugins.unregisterPlugin( 'block-directory' );
```

- Example as a full script:

  ```js
  wp.domReady( () => {
      if ( wp.plugins.getPlugin( 'block-directory' ) ) {
          wp.plugins.unregisterPlugin( 'block-directory' );
      }
  } );
  ```

Comment: Thank you, I dont know how I missed the reference in the doc, this is great.